# pgfplots - x unit, space between label and parantheses

Tags: spacing, pgfplots

Can I specify the space between the label and the parantheses when using x unit in pgfplots? In my example image, I want less space (\,) between the E and the [eV].

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `units` library is not customizable to that extend. But you can simulate the smaller spacing.

The easiest way is to alter the key `unit marking pre` which is used to typeset the left brace/whatever that is needed to denote a unit. Like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[unit marking pre={\!\!\left[}]
    ... 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This will create two negative thin white spaces and will be close to the label.

(i don't have access to a TeX here, but will supply and example later.)

Comment: Thanks. It works but is a little sloppy...

Comment: yeah, but for now it is the only option...